# Make websocket (sockjs) work with spring4 running at GlassFish 3.1.2.2

Tags: websocket, glassfish-3, spring-4, sockjs

I try to create websocket connection using sockjs on client and spring4 (with java config) on backend under GlassFish 3.1.2.2 but whatever I do it always fail with the following problem:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container

[image: browser console]

However it works correctly under Tomcat without any error.

Is there a way to make this work under GlassFish 3.1.2.2? Or should I rewrite Spring java config back to web.xml style? If yes, can somebody show me an example?

Thank you.

I already enabled websocket in http protocol configuration in GlassFish manager and set

```
dynamic.setAsyncSupported(true);
```

in the WebApplicationInitializer.

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(IdCardReaderWebsocketApp.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        final Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(2);
        dynamic.addMapping("/sockjs/*");
        dynamic.setAsyncSupported(true);
    }
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.something.websocket.idcardreader.mock")
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({ IdCardReaderWebsocketConfig.class })
public class IdCardReaderWebsocketApp extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class IdCardReaderWebsocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/idCardReaderWebsocketMockEndpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/mockApp");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/idcard");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I fixed the issue. I had also web.xml file with an other filter. So I added

```
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

to that filter and problem solved. It still failes with ws:// protocol but at least it works with http when sockjs trying.